# Parsing same content twice with lxml.iterparse

Tags: python, lxml, iterparse

I do not get why this works:

```
content = urllib2.urlopen(url)

context = etree.iterparse(content, tag='{my_ns}my_first_tag')
context = iter(context)
#for event, elem in context:
#     pass

context = etree.iterparse(content, tag='{my_ns}my_second_tag')
for event, elem in context:
     pass
```

where this doesn't work:

```
content = urllib2.urlopen(url)

context = etree.iterparse(content, tag='{my_ns}my_first_tag')
context = iter(context)
for event, elem in context:
     pass

context = etree.iterparse(content, tag='{my_ns}my_second_tag')
for event, elem in context:
     pass
```

and gives me this error:

```
XMLSyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document, line 1, column 1
```

Can I not parse the same content twice? Strange that it is working when I just comment the loop and not the whole iterparse command.

Am I missing to close something?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`urllib2.urlopen` gives you a file-like object that you can use to read the contents of the URL you're querying.

I'm guessing here that `etree.iterparse` returns an object that can be iterated but doesn't touch `content` at all until then. In that case, the first loop is using `context` to iterate over the contents of `content`, "consuming" the data as it goes.

When you create the second `context`, you're passing the same `content`, which is "empty" by then.

Edit: as you ask for ways to reparse... One would be to read out the whole data and then pass it separately to each `iterparse` call using `StringIO` as the file-like object. Eg.

```
from StringIO import StringIO

# ...

data = content.read()
context = etree.iterparse(StringIO(data), tag='{my_ns}my_first_tag')
# processing...
context = etree.iterparse(StringIO(data), tag='{my_ns}my_second_tag')
# processing...
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo! Maybe you know how to reset content without doing urlopen again? The best would be to specify more than one tag in the iterparse command but I can not figure out how to do. Thanks again.